KVM Input issues - is my motherboard broken?
I'm trying to diagnose a problem with USB input through a KVM. I have two computers and a KVM:

PC 1: A laptop running linux
PC 2: A desktop dual-booting linux and windows 10
KVM: HDMI+USB, outputs keyboard and mouse through a single cable (I have tried two KVMs, same problem with both)

When using the desktop PC 2 through the KVM, after a while I experience a lot of issues with input -- repeated keys, ignored inputs, mouse glitches etc. Rebooting, unplugging and plugging in the USB cable, and switching the KVM back and forth can make it work again, but it always ends up failing.
Here are all the things I've checked:

Plugging the keyboard and mouse directly into PC 1 or PC 2 works
Using PC 1 through the KVM (on either slot 1 or slot 2 of the KVM) works
Using PC 2 on linux or windows through the KVM has input issues (works for a while then starts glitching)
Even the BIOS screen and boot loader on PC 2 experience input issues through the KVM.
Replaced the KVM with another unit from another brand -- same problems

So it appears that there is a hardware problem with PC 2 when using a KVM. The problem happens regardless of the operating system, it happens with two different KVMs, but it does NOT happen if the mouse and keyboard are plugged directly into the computer.
Is this possible? The only difference I can see is that the KVM sends the keyboard and mouse inputs through a single USB instead of two when they are plugged directly into the machine. Is it possible that the motherboard is broken in a way that would make it sensitive to that? It is an ASUS Prime B650M-A WIFI II
